# Edit memory address of an initialized .data segment word in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

After initializing a word inside the .data segment like this:

```
.data
base: .word 0
```

I need to change the address that 'base' is saved into, inside the .text segment. For example if 'base' is stored in address '268501692', I need to change it into '268501700'

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't rename/readdress memory cell address, so it's not clear what you really want. The `base` is just symbolic name for memory address, once it's 1234, it's 1234. If you want address 2345, then use 2345.

Comment: I want to readdress where that symbolic name points to. Isn't that impossible?

Comment: No, it's compile-time constant, during runtime if you do `la $1,symbol`, it's already fixed value in the machine code of instruction (there's no "symbol" name/string during runtime). This kind of solution doesn't exist in assembler (whatever is your original problem). You *can* self-modify the instruction opcode during runtime to change the values (from 1234 to 2345), but that is considered "code smell" nowadays, and very likely your original problem has different common pattern for solution.

Comment: I basically want to allocate memory through syscall 9, and write the address of v0 (which is the base of the allocated address space) into a .data segment tag, and also being able to manipulate it afterwards.

Comment: I see, that's done other way, indirectly. You store the `v0` to some fixed place like `base`, i.e. `sw $v0,base`, and then before code which will use that allocated memory extensively, you load the address into some spare register like `lw $t6,base`, and then you address through `t6` everything, like `lw $t0,16($t6)` will load word from `t6+16` address. (and `base: .word 0` is used as pointer storage, not data storage) You can then also advance the value in register easily, like `addi $t6,$t6,140` to advance to next element, if allocated memory is some kind of array of elements with 140B size.

Comment: my problem is that I want to have a register which will be used as a pointer. So if I do it in the way you are proposing: First of all`sw $v0, base` doesn't work (I have tried it), and I won't also be able to do this: `lw $t0, $s0($t6)` as it is not a valid command.

Comment: I didn't check with MARS my syntax, just guessing (`sw $v0,(base)` maybe? Or check some tutorials/MARS/SPIM help), so it may be somewhat off... I hope you got the idea. The `lw $t0, $s0($t6)` will not work, because MIPS can't use two registers to address memory. You will have to first calculate final address into some register, like `add $t7, $t6, $s0` `lw $t0,($t7)` (of course you don't need to store `v0` to memory at all, if you can keep it whole time in some register, like s3 or something, then `mov $s3, $v0` is enough to "store" it).

Comment: `sw $v0,(base)` won't work.

Comment: http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm - `sw $v0, base` syntax should work, see second "example:" with `sw $t1, var1`. If it does not work, figure out what is the error message and how that relates... maybe `base` is keyword? unlikely. If you are unable to store/load value into fixed position, why do you even bother with dynamic allocation...

Comment: Well at least in Mars it doesn't work...

Comment: you made me to launch the MARS ... `sw $v0,base` works for me (compiles into expected two instructions `lui` + `sw`), as expected. As I'm not oracle, I can't guess what is your problem and "it doesn't work" is not a proper problem description, nor does it belong to your original question.

Comment: In my case, I do the following: I print the initial `base: .word 0` address like this: `li $v0, 1` `la $a0, base` `syscall` After a syscall 9: `sw $v0, base` (like you said you did) and then in order to see what's the `base` address I reprint but I get the initial address value. It doesn't get the value of `$v0`

Comment: Yes, everything is correct except your expectations... and your debugging methods are a bit from the "desperate" level, when you don't have proper debugger available. In MARS use built-in debugger, and step over single instructions. What you did: `la $a0,base` is assembled into `a0 = 1234` (the compile time constant, representing base address). That will not change by `sw $v0, base`. I suggested to read the allocated address by `lw $t6, base`, that means: `t6 = value_from_address(1234)`. Not `la`. In debugger you should see value in `v0` (allocated adr) is written into memory, later read back.

Comment: If you know already C, then it's probably confusing you... in C you allocate variable like: `int var1 = 0;`, and `var1` in further source means "value of variable", and `&var1` is "address of variable". In assembly it's the other way around: `var1: .word 0` means the assembly will allocate 1 word in memory, set it to value 0, and set symbol `var1` to "address" of that word in memory, while loading from address `base` will load the "value". (i.e. "asm `var1` = C `&var1`" and "asm `(var1)` = C `var1`"). And the syntax of MIPS asm is a bit confusing, where `lw r1,d(r2)` means address `(r2+d)`.

Comment: Maybe re-read my comments, I wrote already all of that before (with almost the same words), in assembly try to pay attention to details and wording, it's often very subtle. Also using the debugger and experimenting with instructions and watching CPU state after each instruction may give you lot of "visual" feedback, how things work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment:

> I basically want to allocate memory through syscall 9, and write the address of v0 (which is the base of the allocated address space) into a .data segment tag, and also being able to manipulate it afterwards.

In C terms, what you're asking is to modify the address of `static int array[]` to set it to the return value of `malloc`.

**That's not how symbols work**.  When you assemble and link, they become fixed numeric addresses.  There's no symbol-table lookup happening when `lw $t0, base($zero)` runs: the the machine-code instruction has the address hard-coded as an immediate constant.  See [a MIPS ISA reference for the encoding format](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).

---

What you should do instead is store that pointer in a register, or in a fixed memory location, i.e. `static int *pointer`.  Then you only have to modify the *value* of the pointer, it still has its own address.  This is an extra level of indirection over a static array, but only if you keep the pointer in memory.  With a pointer in a register, it doesn't matter whether it's pointing to a static array or to dynamically allocated memory.

Don't let C syntax fool you: `pointer[10]` looks the same as `array[10]`, but in the pointer case (with a `static` or global `pointer` variable), the compiler has to emit asm that first loads the pointer from memory, *then* dereferences it.  But in the array case, the address of `array` is a link-time constant, so the compiler can access `array[10]` directly because that's also a link-time constant.